# How to automatically continue numbering of an ordered list?

Tags: html, css

```
I. Introduction
  1. Introduction 1
  2. Introduction 2
II. Services
  3. Services 1
  4. Services 2
```

As you can see in the above example, the number of the second `ol` is started after the last number of the first `ol`.

Of course, I found the attribute `start` but I want to implement it without using that attribute.
Because using the `start` attribute is not dynamic.
If I add one element to the `ol`, I should modify all `start` attributes after that.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please see [ask], then provide some markup in a demo snippet using the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a [CSS counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters) to accomplish this, along with some positioning.

```css
.parent-list {
  counter-reset: child-count;
}

.parent-list ol li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: child-count;
}

.parent-list ol li::before {
  content: counter(child-count)'.';
  position: absolute; 
  left: -1rem;
}
```

```html
<ol class="parent-list">
  <li>Parent One
    <ol>
      <li>Child One</li>
      <li>Child Two</li>
    </ol>
  </li>

  <li>Parent Two
    <ol>
      <li>Child One</li>
      <li>Child Two</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```